# Eclipse doesn't allow me to id resources

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, resources

I've begun learning XML for android and ran into a pretty early error with it. I'm creating an EditText in a RelativeLayout, simple enough. I'm trying to give the EditText an id, but Eclipse keeps giving me this error.

error: Error: Resource type cannot be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@+/newEdit').

This is the activity_main.xml. This could be a simple error, I'm just not sure what is wrong and I couldn't find much help online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has to be `@+id/newEdit` no `@+/newEdit`

Comment: in addition to the answer you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638905/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name/16639012#16639012

Comment: Wow, duh! I knew it was something small that I overlooked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`android:id="@+id/thisViewId"`

You are missing `id`